# Is it possible to disable WiFi throttling on Android(Xamarin.Forms) if the device does not have in Developer Menu this option(Huawei)?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, wifi, throttling, huawei-mobile-services

I'm working on an application in Xamarin.Forms and I try to use nearby Wi-Fi signals for indoor tracking. But it is not possible because of Android Wi-Fi Throttling.

How can I disable it, event my Huawei P20 Pro does not have this option in Developer Menu?

Can be another options to scan efficiently Wi-Fi signals on Android or is not possible as long as Wi-Fi Throttling can't be controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by following this steps [How to quickly install and use ADB](https://www.xda-developers.com/quickly-install-adb/)

And finally I have run this command:

> adb shell settings put global wifi_scan_throttle_enabled 0

That has taken 3 minutes. >))

Answer (score 0):

According to [wifi-scan-throttling docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-throttling), Android 10 has the Wi-Fi Throttling option in Developer Menu.

> **Android 9**: Each foreground app can scan four times in a 2-minute
> period. This allows for a burst of scans in a short time. All
> background apps combined can scan one time in a 30-minute period.

> **Android 10 and higher**: The same throttling limits from Android 9
> apply. There is a new developer option to toggle the throttling off
> for local testing (under **Developer Options** > **Networking** > **Wi-Fi scan**
> **throttling**).

[Huawei P20 (P20/P20 Pro)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_P20) (Android 9) received a system update with Android 10 and EMUI 10 in 2020. You could update it and toggle thethrottling off from Developer Options.

Comment: on EMUI 10 there is no Throttling option. See [link] (https://consumer.huawei.com/uk/community/details/Wi-Fi-scan-throttling-turn-off-option-missing-on-EMUI10/topicId_26798/)  `Wi-Fi scan throttling turn off option missing on EMUI10`

Comment: @Developper Yes, there is no Wi-Fi scan throttling option on EMUI 10. :(